# Camunda Modeler fontsize

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I am having trouble changing the fontsize of a existing model that I didn't make but have to turn into an A3 image. I manage to do that but the rendered letters need to be bigger but I cant make my own plugin or sth.

Comment: The pragmatic way: If you have a decent monitor resolution - you could just use print screen;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export any bpmn diagram as an svg vector image which you could then easily scale to print as A3.